# Manually Commit offsetRanges to Kafka when using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to Consume data from Kafka (0.10.0.0) to Spark (1.6.0) Streaming Application using Kafka Utils Api

`KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, inputTopicsSet)`

The requirement is to commit the Offset Ranges **manually** to the Kafka itself.

Being aware that when using KafkaConsumer (or Consumer) objects in java we can achieve this using commitAsync or commitSync methods after setting  **"enable.auto.commit" = "false"** in params.

I am not able to figure out the the method to do the same when using KafkaUtils.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass  "enable.auto.commit" = "false" as part of `kafkaParams`. In fact you can pass any Kafka consumer setting as part of that.

```
    Map<String, Object> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092,anotherhost:9092");
    kafkaParams.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class);
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", "use_a_separate_group_id_for_each_stream");
    kafkaParams.put("enable.auto.commit", true); 
    //more kafka params goes here if needed
    JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String, StringDecoder, StringDecoder](ssc, kafkaParams, inputTopicsSet)
```

And then commit offset manually like this,

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
  OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

  // some time later, after outputs have completed
  ((CanCommitOffsets) stream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
});
```

Reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html#creating-a-direct-stream

Above code is for spark 2.2.0, it may not be applicable for spark 1.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my requirement is to do manual Commit not auto commit. I was wishing to override the commit code with some additional logic as per my custom requirement and manually trigger it (instead of automatic) but am not able to identify it

Comment: Also, the link you provided is of Spark 2.2.0. It uses the following package which is not available for versions less than 2.0.0
 --    org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010._

Comment: My bad. Although the same link provides information for manually committing the offset, again it may not be applicable with spark 1.6.0.

Comment: Updated the answer for others who are using spark 2.x.